# How to send multidimensional array from JavaScript to PHP in query string

Tags: javascript, json

I am using following code:

```
window.location.assign("index.php?module=pengu_dispatch&action=cover_letter&value="+list);
```

Here I want to send multidimensional array in query string to the PHP file.

Using **JSON** `stringify` function I converted array into string and send, but on PHP side after decoding I am not getting the complete array.

Please let me know what I could be doing wrong

Comment: Dont do this way man !..Use `Ajax`

Comment: Post your php example? Also have you tried using POST instead of a GET? And what about url encoding?

Comment: In jQuery you can use `serializeArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You can put json in a GET param by url encoding it.

```
url = 'http://whatever/some.php?param='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(list))
```

And then in php read it like this

```
$list = json_decode($_GET['param']);
```

Be careful about the size of your list because URL's have a size limit of about 1~2kb. If you want to send a large amount of data you have to use POST.

Comment: On php side i am receiving following dada [{"a2c3e76e-ac85-eb05-05e0-5004561f74b8":["f098992b-7555-7e43-5aa8-4ffbdbcc9d3b","1bf82e34-3c86-811b-76d9-4ffbdbd33a17"],"6a2981c0-d893-d356-b5be-5004436831fb":["b3b7a923-73b7-1bba-269c-501a0e63415a","60bae3eb-ae42-6481-41f2-501a113b2ed8"]}]            But when i am decoding i am not getting an array. I am getting nothing.

Comment: I managed to parse it after removing some weird invisible characters from the string you posted. I'm not sure if they exist in your original data or were added when you posted it in the comment.

Comment: JSON.stringify is not suppose to put weird symbols in your JSON (they were outside of the string literals). You should try and see if the JSON string is OK in the browser before submitting. The only other thing i can think of is some weirdness with encoding GET parameters.